# Existence of a certain smooth function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ whose derivative takes values in $(-1,0]$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, smooth-functions, morse-theory

I am reading *Morse Theory* of Milnor, and in the proof of Theorem 3.2, Milnor says let $\mu:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a smooth function satisfying $\mu(0)>\epsilon$, $\mu(r)=0$ for $r\geq 2\epsilon$, and $\mu'(r) \in (-1,0]$ for all  $r\in \Bbb R$. Here $\epsilon>0$ is a fixed constant. Certainly the first two conditions can be satisfied taking a suitable bump function near $0$, but I can't see how to take $\mu$ such that the third condition holds.

Comment: I think mollification should work

Comment: Is $r$ the variable on the whole real line or only the `radial' part? If it is the former, then nothing is specified on the value of the function for $r\le0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third is also satisfied by 'taking a suitable bump function', so naturally what you are asking for is details. First the idea: you have $2\epsilon$ space. You need to drop down by some amount $h>\epsilon$ at a speed less than 1. Since this is achievable by straight lines  and with room to spare, it should be possible if you don't choose $h$ too big ($h>2\epsilon$.)

Fix $\epsilon$. Consider

$$T(x) = \min(1,\max(1-x,0)).$$
its graph is like `‾\_` where the right angled triangle sits on $[0,1]$. $T(0)=1$. $T'$ is $- 1$ or $0$ except at 2 points. Then setting
$$ T_\epsilon(x) = \frac{3\epsilon}2 T\left(\frac{4x}{7\epsilon}\right)$$
we have $T_\epsilon(0)=\frac{3\epsilon}2>\epsilon$ and $\|T_\epsilon'\|_{L^\infty}\le \frac32 \frac47 = \frac67< 1,$ with the correct sign. Further, $T_\epsilon|_{x>7\epsilon/4}\equiv 0$ so $T_\epsilon|_{x>2\epsilon} \equiv 0$. The only issue is that $T_\epsilon$ isn't smooth. But mollifying with a sufficiently small mollifier (a mollifier supported on $[-\epsilon/4,\epsilon/4]$ makes it begin to be zero exactly at $2\epsilon$), or using a partition of unity, the desired smooth function exists.

PS a similar idea works if you wanted a radial function.

Comment: Thanks. I think $r$ means just a variable not radial. Soprry I don't know about mollifier. How can use a partition of unity to make $T_\epsilon$ smooth?

Comment: @probably123 Hard to believe if you know what a 'suitable bump function' is :) Google standard mollifier. Its convolution with a rescaling of the standard non-negative bump function of integral 1. As for partition of unity, cut out a sufficiently small interval around each of the corners. Making this interval fatter a little, you now have a cover say $U,V,W$ of $\mathbb R$; now patch up with a linear function. The partition of unity subordinate to $U,V,W$ averages the linear function and $T_\epsilon$ in  $U\cap V$ and $V\cap W$, which will preserve the properties you want if you do it right.

Comment: Thanks. I studied analysis by a book of Rudin, and I have never seen mollifier

Comment: Now I see what it is

Comment: @probably123 you're welcome

Comment: My apologies, for both the mollifier approach and the partition of unity, you need to start with a $T_\epsilon$ who is zero a little before $2\epsilon$, as mollification will increase the size of the support. I have edited to reflect this. Also, my comment above, the sets $U,V,W$ are for a single corner. But you just need to repeat this for each corner